# Multiple compiler errors in my quiz program

Tags: java

This is a java program for making a quiz and you have 10 questions and if you get one answer correct you will get 1 point however there is no negative marking and when I compile it it throws this: 'else' without 'if' error

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Write a description of class program1 here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Project
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char ans;
        int score=0;

        System.out.println("1.What was the first mouse created?");
        System.out.println("(a)Glass ");
        System.out.println("(b) Wood");
        System.out.println("(c) Steel");
        System.out.println("(d) Paper");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='b') {
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
            score+=1;
        }
        else {

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");
        }



        System.out.println("2. Who is the father of the 'Internet'?");
        System.out.println("(a)Alan Peris ");
        System.out.println("(c) Vint Cerf");
        System.out.println("(d) Steve Lawrence");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='c')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");




        System.out.println("3.What search engine provides "instant answers" for certain types of queries?");
        System.out.println("(a)Google ");
        System.out.println("(b) Yahoo");
        System.out.println("(c) Bing");
        System.out.println("(d) Dogpile");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='c')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");





        System.out.println("3.4K might be used synonymously with what acronym?");
        System.out.println("(a)UHD ");
        System.out.println("(b) VGA");
        System.out.println("(c) PCI");
        System.out.println("(d) HDR");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='a')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");





        System.out.println("4. A zero day exploit is a type of what?");
        System.out.println("(a) Malware ");
        System.out.println("(b) Shareware");
        System.out.println("(c) Freeware");
        System.out.println("(d) Adware");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='a')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");






        System.out.println("5.What adjective describes an image that only contains         shades of gray?");
        System.out.println("(a) Saturated ");
        System.out.println("(b) Grayscale");
        System.out.println("(c) Hueless");
        System.out.println("(d) Black and White");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='b')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");


        System.out.println("6.What does it mean if a device is erg               onomic?");
        System.out.println("(a) It is upgradeable");
        System.out.println("(b) It is enviromentally friendly");
        System.out.println("(c) It is compatible with multiple               platforms");
        System.out.println("(d) It is designed to be comfortable to use");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='d')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");



        System.out.println("7. Which of the following can be synced with iCloud?");
        System.out.println("(a) Reminders ");
        System.out.println("(b) Contacts");
        System.out.println("(c) Calendar");
        System.out.println("(d) Websites");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='d')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");





        System.out.println("8.What is the term "Wi-Fi" short for?");
        System.out.println("(a) Wireless Fidelity");
        System.out.println("(b) Wireless Finder");
        System.out.println("(c) Wireless Frequency Inte                      lligence");
        System.out.println("(d) Nothing");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='d')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");

        System.out.println("9. What do keystrokes measure?");
        System.out.println("(a) Login attempts");
        System.out.println("(b) Secure socket connections");
        System.out.println("(c) Keys pressed on a keyboard");
        System.out.println("(d) Nothing");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='c')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");




        System.out.println("10.The veronica search engine is used to search what service?");
        System.out.println("(a) Gopher");
        System.out.println("(b) Telnet");
        System.out.println("(c) BBS");
        System.out.println("(d) FTP");
        System.out.print("Enter Your Choice => ");
        ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;
        if(ans=='a')
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
        score+=1;
        else

            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");

        System.out.println("Your total score is:"+score);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you missing the opening and closing brackets for the if statement??

Comment: how can your score be negative? it starts as 0 and you never subtract. anyway, start using methods, instead of constantly repeating code, and don't hard-code answers.

Comment: @Stultuske  our assignement stated that we had to use this method so can you help me with the code?

Comment: I tried that but it never worked... :( @Vini

Comment: the problem is, that if there is only one statement in the if (or else) block, brackets are not needed. The block 'll stop at the closing bracket, or, if there aren't any brackets, at the first ;
of course you need to use the main method, but code like this is very hard to read/maintain. Have you learned about methods yet?

Comment: You are missing brackets around your if block.. Refer to the answer..

Comment: Yes i think I have learnt about the brackets thing but I  solved the problem and can you help me with this it shows an  error: cannot find symbol
ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple ifs with two or more statements.

If you have more than one statement per if, you have to set brackets around this statement. For instance here:

```
if(ans=='b') { // Missing
            System.out.println("That's correct!");
            score+=1;
        } // Missing
        else { // Should be here but not have to, because you only have one statement here.
            System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");
        }
```

Enclosing your statements makes the code more readable. Despite the fact it is unnecessary at some point.

The same error repeats on every if statement in your code. You have to fix it on every of this if-statements.

---

An other error you have made are not escaped `"` within a String. Lets say you have a string

```
String myString = "Hello World";
```

And now you want to write `Hello "the one and only" World`. So you have to escape all " within the string:

```
String myString = "Hello \"the one and only\" World";
```

Comment: Thanks but I still have one question though...error: cannot find symbol
ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your brackets:

```
if(ans=='b'){
    System.out.println("That's correct!");
    score+=1;
}
else
    System.out.println("Sorry it is wrong...");
```

Comment: thanks for that  but I need futher help it shows an error:         error: cannot find symbol
ans=sc.next().charAt(0) ;

Comment: sry, but I cant reproduce that error. Maybe you have a spelling error somewhere (look at line indications of error).